# Missing methods when migrating from odata v2 to v4

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm trying to implement odata v4 for my current master detail app which was using odata v2.

In my app, I used some statements like these.

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().metadataLoaded().then(fnSetAppNotBusy);

var oContext = this.getModel().createEntry(sPath, {
    properties: {
           Name: "ABC",
           Age: "20"
        },
    success: this._fnEntityCreated.bind(this),
        error: this._fnEntityCreationFailed.bind(this)
});
```

I see in this document [Changes Compared to OData V2 Model](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw751abap/7.51.0/de-DE/5d/e13cf4dd1f4a3480f7e2eaaee3f5b8/frameset.htm), odata v4 has replaced metadataLoaded with "corresponding methods".

[image]

I have searched and found some but am not sure if these methods are correct. Can someone please confirm?

[image]

And I can't find method createEntry in oDataModel v4, so how can I implement the same logic as I did with odata v2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. The creation is covered in this example:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.odatav4.06/code

(Basically, you execute the creation on binding/context level)

As for `onMetadataLoaded`, you may use `getMetaModel()` and then use the „appropriate” functions with promises, but I’d go as follows: grab your binding, which is the one you are waiting for, and attach to the event `dataReceived`. E.g.,

```
oTable.getBinding('items').attachEvent('dataReceived', function(){...})
```

The API docs explicitly states that this event is to be used for busy indicators:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding/events/dataReceived

Comment: Hi iPirat,
Regarding your info, it means I can't create or try to wait for metadata loaded without binding to a control, doesn't it?

Comment: In v4 you shouldn’t load the metadata at all, unless necessary. In v2, waiting for metadata to finish loading to change busy state, wasn’t an ideal solution either. Busy state of a control (like a list) should depend on the “data loading” of its binding. This may be more generic though: if you have a page with a table and couple filtering controls, you may want to have whole page as busy while the _data_ in the table is being loaded.